# Angular 2 performance IE11 *ngFor

Tags: performance, angular, internet-explorer-11, ngfor, es6-shim

I'm trying Angular 2 and I noticed that performance on Internet Explorer 11 is dramatically slow while cycling with *ngFor over 1500 items. It takes about 25sec with IE11 whereas less then 1sec on other browsers.

Pausing the debugger I noticed that the code constantly calls **isNan** function in es6-shim.js. 
Here the call stack:

[image]

A working plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/sEujClHmuCbrydIiYQYL?p=preview .
The code is very simple:

```
<ul *ngFor="#item of items">
    <li>Item: {{item.itemKey}}</li>
</ul>

//Load items simulating remote load
setTimeout(function(){
  for (let i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
          self.items.push(new Item(i+""));
      }
},1000);
```

Anyone with the same issue? Any workaround or tip for improving performance?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know if that's really the cause for the poor performance, but other browsers don't need `es6-shim`.

Comment: maybe the is no workaround because IE11 does not have some native implementation and es6-shim is the only way to make the framework work even with poor performance

Comment: Ensure that you have `prodMode` enabled when you test performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that IE has no native implementation of `Map`. The `set` and `get` functions of the polyfill are extremely slow (compared to their native counterparts) and take most of the time:

[image]

Maybe - or hopefully - other polyfills for `Map` are faster than `es6-shim`.

**Update:**

I have tested your code with [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) and its performance seems to be much closer to that of the native implementation.

Comment: Do you have a link to that plunker?  I'm curious which subset of `core-js` you used and whether you have a recommendation on that score.

Comment: IE11 has basic support for `Map` and `Set` built-ins. The polyfill replaces them with its own implementation. I've [patched es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/pull/429) to improve its performance.