# Angular 2 RC 1 Slow in IE 11

Tags: angularjs

I am using these libraries:
       node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js
       node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
       node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js

Performance is really slow, takes few seconds for a simple hello world to show up.

Maybe Systemjs is slow, I am loading angular component via this. Other browsers seem fine.

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: On the Timeline tab in Chrome Developer Tools you can see where are those seconds spent. This is too broad question to answer in this form. FYI System.js use promises and promise heavy solutions are slow in IE/EDGE. The IE/EDGE promise implementation is very slow compared to other implementations. See https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/11329845-improve-promise-implementation-performance and https://www.danyow.net/edge-promise-perf/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is because es6-shim is really slow during get() or set() on a Map object, which is heavily used by Angular2 during change detection. [RC1 switched away from es6-shim](https://github.com/rangle/rangle-starter/issues/86) and uses now [core.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js). [core.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) is a lot faster. In my case, those operations went down from 130ms to 10ms.

Try
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.0/core.min.js"></script>` instead of your es6-shim dependency.

Comment: This definitely helped but still slow compared to chrome.

Comment: Given that es6 has to be shimmed in IE11, it will always be slower than Chrome.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570532/angular-2-performance-ie11-ngfor.